# Howcome refreshing my web app with F5 is extremely slow and hangs, while hitting enter on the address bar refreshes the page instantly?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a web page which uses in PHP and a jQuery DataTable to show data from a database.

When I enter the URL and hit enter, the page loads instantly, and I can do this repeatedly and the page keeps loading instantly.

However, when I hit F5, the page goes blank and hangs, it is trying to load the page but is just too slow.

What would be causing this?

Comment: It might be that hitting enter in the address bar loads your page from the browser cache, while refreshing tries to load it from the server.

Comment: Apologies I didn't know this.. I have done that now and will do so in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you actually confirmed your page is really being reloaded?

Most of the time, hitting enter in the address bar if you're already on the page, will merely cause the browser to load it from its cache. Pressing F5 or reload on the other hand would cause the actual round-trip to the server.

Comment: Yes the page is being reloaded, I have changed some data in the database and some HTML and the changes are visible when I hit enter in the address bar.

Comment: Most likely it then just loads the page itself but none of the additional resources (eg scripts or styles)

Comment: Yes that's what I thought, except that when I make a change to a script or a stylesheet, the changes are visibile when I hit enter.

Comment: I think its a problem with my PHP or Apache set up, or the server its running on.. seems to be taking 8 minutes to load a CSS file when I look at Google Chrome console. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, the page isn't reloaded just by foucsing the address input and pressing enter. If you append some random querystring charaters to your URL you'll force the page to reload. E.g. if your url is http://www.google.com you type http://www.google.com/?randomchars123456etc Then your page will be reloaded and that will probably take as much time as hitting F5

Edit: Don't forget the ? or an & if there already is an ? in your url

Comment: When I do this, it reloads instantly still. However, now when I press F5 with the query string it also reloads instantly. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

When you hit enter, browser loads from cache jquery and other large scripts (but still loading the web page from the net), when you press F5 it reloads all the contents again.